# How to "duplicate" an existing type instead of just aliasing it?

Tags: c++

I run into a situation where I want to use a type alias in the template but don't know how, here's a contrived example:

```cpp
class Example {
  public:
    using A = std::tuple<int, float>;
    using B = std::tuple<int, double>;
    using C = std::tuple<int, double>;
    ....  // possibly many other type aliases

    template<typename T>
    void Foo(const T& value) {
        // do sth ...
    }
};
```

I understand that `A`, `B` and `C` are merely aliases of the original `std::tuple` type, they do not create new types, so in this example, `B` and `C` are different names referring to the same type `std::tuple<int, double>`.

In my case, `T` is going to be one of `A`, `B` and `C`, since `B` is identical to `C`, the compiler will only generate 2 versions of `Foo()`, but I want it to treat `B` and `C` differently. The obvious solution is to replace `std::tuple` with `struct` which defines a new type, but that would make the code a lot more messy and lose the ability of using structured bindings. Is there a more elegant way of achieving this? Or should I prefer using `struct` in this case?

Comment: There isn't. You can use structured bindings on structs just fine.

Comment: I can't tell what's the difference between B and C and so does your compiler. If they are different, then struct should be better.

Comment: Is this an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)?

Comment: Use two template arguments for `Foo`, e.g. an `int` in addition to `T`. OR use `struct` for the template argument, but not for the function argument. The struct may contain the `using I = ... ` and contain no member variable and the function argument could be `T::I`.

Comment: @PasserBy Thanks for pointing out, didn't know that...

Comment: @Enlico This isn't a weird requirement, there's plenty of reasons to want this. See boost strong typedef for example.

Comment: @Sebastian Thanks, I think your second approach is what I'm looking for.

Comment: See also https://github.com/joboccara/NamedType